# Sendable DE Column passed as String Parameter in CloudPage URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobilepush, cloudpage, inbox

We are working on implementing APP Inbox messages. When we create an Inbox message in MobilePush studio it generates a CloudPage URL. I am looking for editing this auto-generated CloudPage URL to include a Data Extension column name passing it as a string parameter.

For example, the URL generated is `https://pub.sX.exacttarget.com/XXXXXXXXX/` and I want to pass a DE column called InsertDate in the URL as a parameter.

I have tried it like this `https://pub.sX.exacttarget.com/xxxxxxxx/?date=%%=AttributeValue("InsertDate")=%%`

And then in my CloudPage I am using Ampscript to get this value:

```
%%[

SET @passeddate = Requestparameter("date")
SET @AccountBalance = Lookup("DEName", "DEColumn", "Lookupcolumn", Lookypvalue)

]%%

Account Balance on %%=v(@passeddate)=%% is %%=v(@AccountBalance)=%%
```

The problem is when I trigger this Inbox message, I get the message in my APP inbox  where the URL is being shown as

`url: https://pub.sX.exacttarget.com/xxxxxxxx/?date=`

and when I tap on it within the Inbox, the message displayed is Account Balance on is `$xx.xx` whereas I am expecting the message to be

`Account Balance on "date(whatever date is in the data extension)" is $xx.xx`

Looking for suggestions to get the correct value from DE.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `InsertDate` attribute value contain any [reserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)? If so, it may need to be [URL encoded](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/urlencode.htm) first:

```
https://pub.sX.exacttarget.com/xxxxxxxx/?date=%%=URLEncode(AttributeValue("InsertDate"),1,1)=%%
```

Comment: Thank You @Mark. I tried your suggestion but still no luck. The InsertDate is SFMC's default date format and has the value 4/18/2019 3:09:23 PM.

Comment: there is also a column named "ShortDate" and has value 4/18. I tried with both value but it is not showing up in the URL when the Inbox message is received on the APP.  url: https://pub.sX.exacttarget.com/xxxxxxxx/?date=                                                   
  This inbox message is an API triggered and I am invoking https://www.exacttargetapis.com/push/v1/messageContact/xxxxxxxx/send by passing the deviceToken

Comment: @SudhirKumar For testing purposes, what happens if you hardcode a static string (e.g., `?date=test`), same result?

Comment: On passing static string test, the URL received in the APP Inbox is pub.sX.exacttarget.com/xxxxxxxx/?date=test and when I tap on it, the message displayed is "Account Balance on test is $xx.xx. I believe the issue may be with passing the DE column name, as "InsertDate" is NOT a Subscriber's attribute in MobilePush demographic. I am going to try with passing NOW() in the URL and will update you with the result.

Comment: looks like we can not pass a Data Extension column name is the URL as it is not a Subscriber attribute. I passed NOW() and it works. https://pub.sX.exacttarget.com/xxxxxxx/?date=%%=Format(Now(),”MM/dd/yyyy”)=%% but working with date will not be the right approach. I am wondering if there is any way to pass a DE Column in the URL which is not a subscriber attribute.

Comment: @SudhirKumar If the column is named "InsertDate" and part of the audience DE, have you tried using a substitution string instead? E.g., `?date=%%InsertDate%%`

Comment: Yes @Mark. This was the first thing I tried when I started working on it. But since it did not work, I started exploring other options like including AttributeValue().

Comment: @SudhirKumar Have you explored using the `%%mobile_number%%` / `%%emailaddr%%` / `%%subscriberid%%` [personalization strings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) with a Lookup in some way? E.g., `?date=%%=Lookup('someDE', 'InsertDate', 'someSubscriberField', mobile_number)=%%`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92761/discussion-between-sudhir-kumar-and-mark-g).

Comment: Thank You for all your time Mark but my use case requires me to show Account Balance to user when they tap on the inbox message. Now if the User taps on the inbox message which was send to them 3 days ago, I will have to show them the Account Balance of 3 days ago(A DE holds these value and will have n number of rows for this subscriber). I need to know which days Account Balance they are requesting for. Doing a Lookup will not help because when the user would tap on any message, this lookup will get n number of rows(even LookupRows, LookUpOrderedrows will not help).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to wait till the april release

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2019_mp_jb_entry_source_personalization.htm&type=5

The other thought is does date exist in the DE you are doing the lookup so it doesn't have to be passed in the url?

Comment: Thanks @EazyE but my usecase requires me to pass the date in the URL. We would be sending out Account Alerts to our users daily. All those alerts will be in the Inbox. Now when a user taps on a message which was sent 7 days ago, I would need the date so that I can query the DE for that particular day and show the balance.